# Is it ok to trust regression predictions when none of the coefficients are statistically significant?

Tags: linear-regression

Background to the problem: I am estimating individual treatment effects using [double machine learning model](https://economics.mit.edu/files/12538). I do not know true treatment effects for my problem.

Double ML: Given Y (outcome), T (treatment) and X ( features)

Y = aT + bX + error

coefficient a is of interest (measures treatment effect) .

Double ML procedure:

1. Fit Y ~ X  => Compute residuals (Y* = Y – Y’) – Residuals are
   treatment effects to be estimated
2. Fit T ~ X => Compute residuals (T* = T- T’) – This model captures
   variation in T explained by X
3. Fitting a model (Y* ~ T* ) on residuals will give the average
   treatment effects

I am fitting a linear regression model (Y* ~ T* ) and none of the coefficients are statistically significant. Instead of relying on point estimates, I am computing prediction confidence intervals and p-value to check if the predicted value is statistically significant or not.

Is this approach good?

Comment: Is the model overall significant? And I don’t follow how you’re proceeding with prediction confidence intervals (sounds oxymoronic) and p-values of the predicted values. Please elaborate,

Comment: I updated my question with more details

Comment: Have you considered variable interactions? Are T and X correlated? Have you tried any transformations?

Comment: Show the full regression outcome, including all statistics

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the goal of the project.

Statistical significance is more important for publishing in academic journal. For applied projects, statistical significance is less important.

Even if a model is not statistical significant, it can have value. The model may summarize the data and identify relationships. The model maybe practically important, the effect maybe of value to practitioners.